# Elasticsearch query term

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to get a course with a title or body "prueba":

Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query" : {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "prueba",
                    "fields": ["title","body"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
"_index": "content",
"_type": "comment_thread",
"_id": "5c3c79298115f61cc2000000",
"_score": 1.4054651,
"_source": {
"_id": "5c3c79298115f61cc2000000",
"body": "Hola esto es una prueba",
"commentable_id": "course",
"context": "course",
"course_id": "course-v1:edx+CC101+2019_T1",
}
```

Okey, it's perfect. Now I want to do the same search but adding the exact course_id. So:

Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query" : {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "prueba",
                    "fields": ["title","body"]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "term" : { "course_id": "course-v1:edx+CC101+2019_T1" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result: 0 hits

But if I put `"term" : { "course_id": "course" }` return the course....

What's it happening?

Mapping:

```
"course_id": {
    "type": "string"
},
```

ElasticSearch version:

```
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "MN-E (Ultraverse)",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Please post your mapping and Elasticsearch version..

Comment: Most probably your `course_id` field is of type `text`. If you're using ES 5+ try to use `course_id.keyword` instead. Otherwise, provide your mapping as suggested by Ryan.

Comment: @ryanlutgen Added

Comment: @Val course_id type is string

Comment: Which version of ES are your running? v2?

Comment: @Val Added to the post.

Comment: Ok, then in order for your query to work, your `course_id` field needs to be `"type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"`

Comment: @Val okey, how can I do that? thanks in advance

Comment: You need to modify your mapping and reindex your data

Comment: @Val I did a PUT with:

 {
  "comment_thread": {
    "properties": {
      "course_id": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}

And now the mapping is: "course_id": {
"type": "string",
"norms": {
"enabled": false
}
},

But keep not working...

Comment: See the second part of my answer... you need to reindex your data after modifying your index mapping